# Enabling UIPanGestureRecognizer on UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

i am using UIPanGestureRecognizer and UILongPressGestureRecognizer on UIScrollView. i am disabling UIPanGestureRecognizer on viewWillAppear so my scroll works perfectly

```
appRecognizer.enabled=NO;
```

and when user long tap on view i am enabling UIPanGestureRecognizer in longtap method

```
appRecognizer.enabled=YES;
```

the issue is UIPanGestureRecognizer selector Method is not calling until i leave tap and press again.
i have multiple GestureRecognizer on multiple UIView.i have tried

```
[self ViewMove:appRecognizer];
```

but having issue with state of view.

what is the best way to handle this issue. how to call perfectly selector method of UIPanGesture on Long Tap.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` method on one of your gesture recognizers?
Pass the other `UIGestureRecognizer` as an argument.

If it's not working, try swapping the argument and receiver gesturerecognizer around. Should solve your problem!

Comment: Is there any way to call uipan selector with passing current tapped view